# Microsoft Outlook - collaborating with colleagues - being informed of task completion

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email

I hope someone can help.

I work as part of a team where more process driven requests are sent to a centralised admin team.

In my role, if I receive such a request from a member of staff, I will forward it on to this centralised team.  These e-mails quite often have attachments.

This centralised team use a Shared Mailbox to receive these e-mails.  This mailbox does not have the Emoji facility whereby the recipient can respond with say a "thumbs up" when the task has been completed.

At the moment, I bcc myself into any e-mails I send to this shared mailbox so I have a record of the tasks I've allocated

**The problem:** When I send e-mail to this shared inbox, I would like a way of being able to see when these e-mails have been actioned.  The emoji feature would have enable this allowing the team to "thumbs up" completed tasks, but the mailbox has not been set up to allow this.

**What I've tried so far:** I've tried sharing a "To-Do" list in Outlook with the admin team, but with this any attachments are lost.

Is there a way of using 'Follow Up' flags or other suggestions?

Comment: Why not add sub-folders to the shared box, "New", "In Progress" and "Done"? You could even have "In Progress - Person A", "In Progress - Person B"... but longer term, maybe you need to look at using Jira, ADO or something like that.

Comment: It looks like you need to see how your team collaboration is progressing, i'm afraid that this is hard to achieve in the Outlook client. And I recommend checking out Microsoft VIVA Goals(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introducing-microsoft-viva-goals-bd651be7-472a-4f40-8fdd-6fcead79f3ad).